# C++11 regex matching capturing group multiple times

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, ecmascript-5

Could someone please help me to extract the text between the : and the ^ symbols using a JavaScript (ECMAScript) regular expression in C++11.  I do not need to capture the `hw-descriptor` itself - but it does have to be present in the line in order for the rest of the line to be considered for a match.  Also the `:p....^`, `:m....^` and `:u....^` can arrive in any order and there has to be at least 1 present.

I tried using the following regular expression:

```
static const std::regex gRegex("(?:hw-descriptor)(:[pmu](.*?)\\^)+", std::regex::icase);
```

against the following text line:

```
"hw-descriptor:pTEXT1^:mTEXT2^:uTEXT3^"
```

Here is the code which posted on a **[live coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef175ee3830226d0)**.  It shows how I attempted to solve this problem, however I am only getting 1 match.  I need to see how to extract each of the potential 3 matches corresponding to the p m or u characters described earlier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    static const std::regex gRegex("(?:hw-descriptor)(:[pmu](.*?)\\^)+", std::regex::icase);
    std::string foo = "hw-descriptor:pTEXT1^:mTEXT2^:uTEXT3^";
    // I seem to only get 1 match here, I was expecting 
    // to loop through each of the matches, looks like I need something like 
    // a pcre global option but I don't know how.
    std::for_each(std::sregex_iterator(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), gRegex), std::sregex_iterator(), 
        [&](const auto& rMatch) {
            for (int i=0; i< static_cast<int>(rMatch.size()); ++i) {
                std::cout << rMatch[i] << std::endl;
            }
        });
}
```

The above program gives the following output:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
hw-descriptor:pTEXT1^:mTEXT2^:uTEXT3^
:uTEXT3^
TEXT3
```

Comment: Repeated capturing groups re-write its buffer upon each match (quantifier iteration). You need to check if the `hw-descriptor` is present separately. Or capture the whole block and then use another matching code once you find a valid group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you show me how I might do that in the live code?   The demo is a stripped down version of a multi like regular expression - only 1 like contains a repeated capturing group - could I re-express the regex to have an optional 'p' group, followed by an optional 'm' group followed by an optional 'u' group with at least 1 of these 3 groups matching?  Just an idea but I have not been succcessful putting together such a regex so far

Comment: You cannot do that with the C++ regex. Use multiple matching like in http://ideone.com/8WFLJa. Is this approach ok for you?

Comment: Note that there is no infinite width (any) lookbehind, nor `\G` operator in C++ std::regex. You cannot do that with 1 regex.

Comment: You do not say if anything can be between the _blocks_. However, it's a two step process, Validate and capture-al blocks in one step, then pull individual blocks in another. Step 1 `^(?:hw-descriptor)(.*?:[pmu]\^.*)` Step 2 `:([pmu])(.*?)\^` Step 2 uses the capture buffer from step 1 as a target string and is done globally.

Comment: You might want to use Boost library otherwise. There,  you would be able to either use `\G` based regex, or even access capture collection (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/captures.html).

Comment: Or a later version boost regex: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/captures.html. I would stick with what you've got now and do it in 2 steps though. The other option's would probably be a link and setup nightmare for you. If you need more power than ecmascript can offer, it might be worth either pcre of boost-perl-like stuff. _Note that boost regex Repeated Captures is problematic at best (see the performance disclaimer)_.

Comment: This is a straightforward text search; it would take about fifteen minutes to write the search code with the member functions of `std::string`, and the resulting code would be clean and maintainable.

Comment: Hmmm interested in boost option as the app is currently working with boost 1.61, nice.

Comment: Agreed, however the actual regex is much more complex as its matching multiple banners in an FTP server response.  Regex gives me a lot of flexibility.

Comment: You don't need to use boost regex, but if you do, you have to be careful how you define the global flags. Setting them wrong will cause all kinds of gotcha problems.

Comment: With Boost, you may use `(?:hw-descriptor|(?!^)\G):([^^]*)\^`  regex (see https://regex101.com/r/pD2rZ9/1) and access Group 1 captures.

Comment: If my answer helped you please consider accepting.

Answer (score 5):

With `std::regex`, you cannot keep mutliple repeated captures when matching a certain string with consecutive repeated patterns.

What you may do is to match the overall texts containing the prefix and the repeated chunks, capture the latter into a separate group, and then use a second smaller regex to grab all the occurrences of the substrings you want separately.

The first regex here may be

```
hw-descriptor((?::[pmu][^^]*\\^)+)
```

See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/uRWvgx/1). It will match `hw-descriptor` and `((?::[pmu][^^]*\\^)+)` will capture into Group 1 one or more repetitions of `:[pmu][^^]*\^` pattern: `:`, `p`/`m`/`u`, 0 or more chars other than `^` and then `^`. Upon finding a match, use `:[pmu][^^]*\^` regex to return all the real "matches".

[C++ demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a5894b1ebd9f0f2):

```
static const std::regex gRegex("hw-descriptor((?::[pmu][^^]*\\^)+)", std::regex::icase);
static const std::regex lRegex(":[pmu][^^]*\\^", std::regex::icase);
std::string foo = "hw-descriptor:pTEXT1^:mTEXT2^:uTEXT3^ hw-descriptor:pTEXT8^:mTEXT8^:uTEXT83^";
std::smatch smtch;
for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(foo.begin(), foo.end(), gRegex);
                         i != std::sregex_iterator();
                         ++i)
{
    std::smatch m = *i;
    std::cout << "Match value: " << m.str() << std::endl;
    std::string x = m.str(1);
    for(std::sregex_iterator j = std::sregex_iterator(x.begin(), x.end(), lRegex);
                         j != std::sregex_iterator();
                         ++j)
    {
        std::cout << "Element value: " << (*j).str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Match value: hw-descriptor:pTEXT1^:mTEXT2^:uTEXT3^
Element value: :pTEXT1^
Element value: :mTEXT2^
Element value: :uTEXT3^
Match value: hw-descriptor:pTEXT8^:mTEXT8^:uTEXT83^
Element value: :pTEXT8^
Element value: :mTEXT8^
Element value: :uTEXT83^
```