# std::regex: Match string consisting of digits and white space and extract digits. How?

Tags: c++, regex

I want to do 2 things at the same time: Match a string against a pattern and extract groups.

The string consists of white spaces and digits. I want to match the string against this pattern. Additionally I want to extract the digits (not numbers, single digits only) using std::smatch.

I tried a lot, but no success.

For the dupe hunters: I checked many many answers on SO, but I could not find a solution.

Then I tried to use the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. And the result was also baffeling me. In

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

const std::regex re1{ R"(((?:\s*)|(\d))+)" };

const std::regex re2{ R"(\s*(\d)\s*)" };

int main() {
    std::string test("   123 45 6   ");
    std::smatch sm;

    bool valid1 = std::regex_match(test, sm, re1);
    std::vector<std::string> v(std::sregex_token_iterator(test.begin(), test.end(), re2), {});
    return 0;
}
```

The vector contains not only the digits, but also spaces. I would like to have digits only.

The `smatch` does not contain any digits.

I know, that I can first remove all whitespaces from the string, but there should be a better, one step solution.

---

What is the proper regex to 1. match the string against my described pattern and 2. extract all single digits into the smatch?

Comment: Try `\s*\d`, it will match 0+ spaces and then single digit

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: Sorry, does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you need to validate is

```
\s*(?:\d\s*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xRMZj3/3) (note I added `^` and `$` to make the pattern match the whole string at the regex testing site, since you use equivalent `regex_match` in the code, it requires a full string match).

Next, once your string is validated with the first regex, you just need to extract any single digit:

```
const std::regex re2{ R"(\d)" };
// ...
std::vector<std::string> v(std::sregex_token_iterator(test.begin(), test.end(), re2), {});
```

Full [working snippet](https://ideone.com/06rHK4):

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

const std::regex re1{ R"(\s*(?:\d\s*)*)" };

const std::regex re2{ R"(\d)" };

int main() {
    std::string test("   123 45 6   ");
    std::smatch sm;

    bool valid1 = std::regex_match(test, sm, re1);
    std::vector<std::string> v(std::sregex_token_iterator(test.begin(), test.end(), re2), {});
    for (auto i: v)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

**Alternative solution using Boost**

You may use a regex that will match all digits separately only if the whole string consists of whitespaces and digits using

```
\G\s*(\d)(?=[\s\d]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JnykVh/1).

**Details**

- `\G` - start of string or end of the preceding successful match
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d)` - a digit captured in Group 1 (we'll return only this value when passing `1` as the last argument in `boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(test.begin(), test.end(), re2, 1)`)
- `(?=[\s\d]*$)` - there must be any 0 or more whitespaces or digits and then the end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [whole C++ snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/066386412811eb4b) (compiled with the `-lboost_regex` option):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string test("   123 45 6   ");
    boost::regex re2(R"(\G\s*(\d)(?=[\s\d]*$))");
    boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(test.begin(), test.end(), re2, 1);
    boost::sregex_token_iterator end;
    std::vector<std::string> v(iter, end);
    for (auto i: v)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The ````(\d)```` was clear to me. I was wondering, why I got the spaces, although only the ````(\d)```` was in the group (in brackets). OK, anyway. More important is the ````std::sregex_match```` for me. The naive approach for the match would be ````(\s|\d)*````. But this will not put any digit in a group and, what I wanted, in the smatch result. And that is my worrying point. How to match and get the result (via smatch) at the same time?

Comment: @ArminMontigny You must be asking about [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). No, it is not possible with `std::regex`. With Boost, you [could get something working](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/captures.html), but you would need to compile it in a specific way, and some people say it is more a headache than a solution. See [another 2-step workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53117367/3832970).

Comment: @ArminMontigny See an alternative solution using Boost.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Understood . . . .  But wondering why standard C++ cannot handle such a simple task. Anyway +1 +accept.

Comment: @ArminMontigny Because none of its supported regex flavors supports `\G` or infinite-width lookbehind. Nor capture stack for each group.